# Show content according to specific geographical location

Tags: php, jquery, geolocation, geocoding

I am developing a dynamic image carousel. The images/banners shown in the carousel will be region specific. I have divided the regions into four section:

1. UK (R1)
2. AUSTRALIA (R2)
3. EUROPE (R3)
4. REST OF THE WORLD (R4)

My primary logic is, split these region using IP range (which is shown above in the brace).
My requirement is how to split all these worldwide IP ranges into these particular four regions.

Suggestions and referral links are appreciable.

Comment: check geoip from http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/, you can use the country database, it will return the country code and continent. It also comes as a php extension